# Tic Tac Toe, checking legal move

Tags: java

New to the site and have not been coding long. I am trying to find a way to check to see if the entered value is withing the array range as well as checking to see if the position is already occupied. I am running into trouble if the problems are not in order. I would like for it to catch the problem in any order and request them to enter another value, then recheck again. Thanks for any advice!

This is what I ended up doing. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

```
//in play game method
while(checkNotInBounds(move)){
        System.out.println("Out of Bounds! Please try again...");
        move = getMove(player);          
     } 
     while(!checkSpaceFree(move, boardValues)){
        System.out.println("Space Taken! Please try again...");
        move = getMove(player);  

        while(checkNotInBounds(move)){
        System.out.println("Out of Bounds! Please try again...");
        move = getMove(player);          
     } 



//Method: checkInBounds
//Purpose: find out if move is in bounds
public static boolean checkNotInBounds(int[] move){
  if(move[0] > 2 || move[0] < 0 || move[1] > 2 || move[1] < 0){
     return true;}
  return false;
}     

//Method: checkFreeSpace
//Purpose: find if space is free 
public static boolean checkSpaceFree(int[] move, char[][]boardValues){         
  if(boardValues[move[0]][move[1]] == ' '){
     return true;}
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the problems are "not in order"?

Comment: Sorry to be vague...If the user entered a "out of bounds" error 1st then a "space taken" error it would catch it. Otherwise it would crash. I believe it is in my logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not split it up into two methods instead of one as your trying to do two things there and switching isn't neccary then

do something like

```
public static boolean checkLegalMove(int[] move, char[][] boardValues){
  if(move[0] > 2 || move[0] < 0 || move[1] > 2 || move[1] < 0){
   return false;
 } 
  if(boardValues[move[0]][move[1]] != ' '){           
    return false;
 }
 return true;
 }

public void doSomething(boolean checkLegalMove(move,boardValues), char player){
 boolean check = checkLegalMove(move,boardValues);
 char temp = player;

if(check ==true ){
 //do something to player
 }else{
  getMove(player);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should be split into 2 (or more) methods.  Could you elaborate on how that should be done?  Perhaps provide an example.